# return a list of lists from a text file

Tags: python-3.x

```
results = open(filename, 'r')


   line = results.readline()
   while line != '':
    # results for a single draw
    star = line[line.rfind('\t') :]
    stars.append(star)
    line =results.readline()
'''

while line != '':


   main = [line[:line.rfind('\t')]]
   mains.append(main)
   line =results.readline()
return (mains)
```

I am using the above script to read from a text file in the format 1,2,3,4,5 tab 9,10new line 6,7,8,9,10 tab 11,12 and am trying to get back [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]The above script gives me [['1,2,3,4,5'],['6,7,8,9,10']] -the parentheses prevent me using the data. Forgive me for once again being stupid, but how do I get the list format back from the text file? I did try to read other posts, but haven't been able to apply the suggestions - too new to this
Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
# say your data is in file named 'testfile'
$ cat testfile 
1,2,3,4,5   9,10
6,7,8,9,10  11,12

# the actual code
datafile = [line.strip().split('\t')[0].split(',') for line in open('testfile')]   
result = []
for l in datafile:
    result.append([int(string) for string in l])
# test the results
print(result)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

**EDIT**:
For getting both parts of each line, try:

```
datafile = [line.strip() for line in open('testfile')]
datafile = [line.split('\t') for line in datafile if line]
datalist = list(zip(*datafile))
result = []
for index in datalist:
    for i in index:
        result.append([int(string) for string in i.split(',')])
# you can access the result list by indexing:
print(result[:2], result[2:])
# or assign to new lists:
firstlist, secondlist = result[:2], result[2:]
print(firstlist, secondlist)
```

Comment: This works brilliantly. Thank you very much. I am trying to understand, though, why it works. Why does this 'remove' the ' ' from the returned numbers?

Comment: @user1478335 `'1'` is a string object and it supports entirely different set of operations than `1` (an integer object). E.g. `'1' + '2'` yields `'12'` (it concatenates strings together), and `1 + 2` gets you `3` (it performs a simple summing operation). If you need integer objects, you need to convert strings to integers by using `int('1')`. So the code splits first the lines, so that you remove the part after tabs, then it splits the returned strings using `','` as a separator, then you have 1-character-long strings in a list and the code converts them into integers by using `int(string)`.

Comment: THank you. One more daft question. If I want to return the second sets ( containing the two numbers) how do I change the datafile declaration? I cannot seem to be able to define their position properly. Was using [line.rfind('\t')+1 :line.rfind('\n')].split()

Comment: @user1478335 The second part (after the tab sign) of each line is not added to the `datafile` list (because of the index `[0]` used - only first part is added). Basically you'd need to move some editing (like splitting by commas) further down in th code. I will edit the answer and provide code which will allow retrieving both parts of each line.

Comment: I get with the modified function : result.append([int(string) for string in i.split(',')])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Ok, so I suspect that you have empty lines in the file and they cause the problem. I modified the code a bit again, try now.

Comment: MAy I ask one last question,please. Iwant to be able to count all the numbers within a decile eg 1-9 etc. For this I want the file in the format[1,2,3,4,...,n] Can you read from a text file in the format 1,2,3,4,5 tab 8,11 new line 5,6,7,8,9 tab 4,45 new line to get this format?

Comment: I am not sure what result you actually expect, but if it is all numbers within a file in one list, I'd try: `result = []; for line in open('file').readlines(): for i in line.strip().split(','): if i.isdigit(): result.append(int(i)); if '\t' in i: for part in i.split('\t'): result.append(int(part))`, with proper line separation and indentation, of course.

Comment: Thank you. Excellent. I am still having trouble returning only the sets containing the two numbers alone

Comment: If you mean you want to have lists of only those numbers after tab character in each line, then split the `result` list in half and use the latter part (say, by using `endings = result[int(len(result) / 2):]`).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
results = open(filename, 'r')
line = results.readline()
mains = []
while line != '':
  stars = line[:line.rfind('\t')].split(',')
  nums = [int(n) for n in stars]
  mains.append(nums)
  line =results.readline()
```

Comment: Gives me:nums = [int(n) for n in stars] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: As usual, I appear to have done something wrong!!

Comment: Are you sure that your input file contains TAB character? Some editor puts space instead of TAB when you press TAB key. Use notepad to create your input file. If that does not help then replace the line with: nums = [int(n) for n in stars if n]